# Unfeatured products

Tags: magento-1.8, product

I've imported a new category of products to my website from csv file using Magmi. The import was successful and i can see the products in the backend.The problem is that they don't show up in my category view and when i check i saw that "Featured product" is set to "No".

How can i change that attribute for all my 300 products?

If you have any easy straightforward way to do so, i will be very grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Catalog > Manage products you have at the top right Actions, you can select Update Attributes from there after you select all your products in the list.

[image: update attributes]

Comment: That got the job done. Thank you so much :)